# Are frozen berries safe in overnight oats?

Tags: food-safety, frozen, raspberries

As far as I know, frozen berries are safe when eaten while still frozen, when cooked directly from frozen, or when carefully thawed and eaten quickly. When they are left at room temperature for too long bacteria growth makes them unsafe to eat.

If frozen berries are added when making overnight oats, and kept in the refrigerator, are they safe the next morning? Are they safe the following morning?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your concern, or your recipe. At what point in the process are the berries at room temperature?

Comment: They are never at room temperature. I probably have an irrational fear of thawing food!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your scenario the berries never go above fridge temperature so there are no safety concerns.